# Redirecting to domain root but storing the original url request

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Hi what I want to do is take an url like: `http://mydomain.com/google.com` and parse it so it opens google.com in an iframe. The goal is to be able to open any site on mydomain.com in iframe but have users submit their desired site with `http://mydomain.com/<somesite>` for example: `http://mydomain.com/youtube.com` would open youtube in iframe.
The problem is that appending the site to the url like that obviously returns 404 not found. I'm guessing some htaccess magic is needed here but I am no good with it.

So how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Yup, you need a `.htaccess` magic. Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^u/(.+)? http://$1 [L]
```

That is:

> If you find a request for *`/u/something`*, redirect it to *`http://something`*.

And then in your HTML:

```
<a href="http://yourdomain.com/u/google.com" target="yourIframeName">Link</a>
```

I placed the `/u/` part because without that it's hard for your website to make other page work apart from `index.php`. We need a way to distinguish between *normal* URLs and *iframe redirections*.